# What is wrong with this python code (list operation)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset and I extracted them based on sentence_level, it means, each sentence is an element of a list.

```
REL_LIST = np.array(['CEO', 'born', 'Professor', 'Employee', 'president']) # Relationship
len(SENT_LIST) # is 4 (`SENT_LIST` is list of sentences from a file)

len(REL_LIST) # is 5 (`REL_LISt` is the words or relations in each sentence)

vector1 # is a numpy array, contains those elements extracted by NAMED ENTITY Recognition of Polyglot. such as (I-PER(['M.', 'Ashraf']) I-LOC(['Afghanistan'])

LEN_SENT = 0
word = 0
while word <= len(REL_LIST):
    if REL_LIST[word] in SENT_LIST[LEN_SENT][:]:
        k = np.insert(vector1[LEN_SENT], word, REL_LIST[word])
        print(k) # `vector1` is a numpy array include NER from polyglot.
    LEN_SENT = LEN_SENT + 1
    word = word + 1
    if LEN_SENT == len(SENT_LIST) and word == LEN_SENT:
        break # because length of `sentence` and `REL_LIST` is not the same
```

It only outputs the relationship of the first element but not all. why?

```
 ['President' I-PER(['M.', 'Ashraf']) I-LOC(['Afghanistan'])]
```

Comment: please, replace your example with english only, if you want to get fast correct help.

Comment: @BearBrown, I changed it into English, but mostly I face the problem with Dari language.

Comment: What exactly do you want? I mean how you want to input and output be? @user2988094

Comment: this code sample has some variables not defined add the complete code

Comment: @Soften98, at the end line I have mentioned that it only output one element not all, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: @AhmedYousif, I tried to keep it short, but I gave comments, what variables for.

Comment: @user2988094 you have to add current state of these variables declared to trace it

Comment: @AhmedYousif, for example, the current state of which variable?, I added more comments, check it out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You increment both `LEN_SENT` and `word` at the same time.
That is the problem.

To check every word for every sentence, you need two nested loops.

Try something like:

```
LEN_SENT = 0
word = 0
for LEN_SENT in range(len(SENT_LIST)):
    for word in range(len(REL_LIST)):
        if REL_LIST[word] in SENT_LIST[LEN_SENT][:]:
            k = np.insert(vector1[LEN_SENT], word, REL_LIST[word])
            print(k) # `vector1` is a numpy array include NER from polyglot.
```

Comment: It gives two outputs with an error. Just it took one element from the `REL_LIST` and added into two elements of `vector1`. and the error is: ` IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`

Comment: maybe provide a full example with `SENT_LIST` and `vector1` contents that you are executing the code with. Then it would be much easier to provide you with the answer you need.